# Ansible: override variables

Tags: variables, ansible, overriding, roles

how could I override variable in following situation:
playbook/roles/role1/defaults/main.yml

```
# Example1
myvars:
  var1: val1
  var2: val2
```

I'd like to override only 1 variable from this hash, something like

```
# Example1
myvars:
  var2: val2-new
```

I've added to playbook.yml following construction:

```
vars_files:
  - vars/local_conf_options.yml
```

vars/local_conf_options.yml has content from Example2
And I get error about undefined variable var1.

How I could resolve this issue?

PS: I've tried to rename 'defaults' to 'vars', but got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify [hash_behaviour](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) to `merge`. The default is `replace`.

But be careful, this is global setting! Some other parts of your playbooks may break because of this change.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a depricated since 1.9

Comment: Also in documentation I see: "New in version 2.0.
If you want to merge hashes without changing the global settings, use the combine filter described in Filters." 
But I don't understand how filters could help with prioritization...

Comment: It is not deprecated. `combine` will not help you to automatically handle this. `combine` is used to merge different dictionaries into single one.

Comment: it's exactly what I told about filters.
Btw, you're right about deprication, I've double-checked and found that I misread(it was about hostfile).